# git diff between staged changed and HEAD repository

Tags: git

I am new to git and I wanted to know how to list differences between my staging directory and HEAD.

Here is the scenario:

1. cherrypicked a commit and ended up with merge conflicts.
2. resolved the merge conflicts and  staged them.
3. Now, I checked git diff --cached and git diff...but they donot show the difference between staged directory and latest upstream repository(HEAD).

Comment: What does `git diff --cached` actually show?  It is the correct command to be using.

Comment: it shows the diff between staged changes and cloned copy of source code

Comment: i want the diff between staged changes and upstream repository(on server)

Comment: Git never does operations like diff across a link.  You must fetch the latest content from the server and then compare it: `git fetch origin master`, `git diff --cached FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: @jszakmeister: i can accept your answer if you convert your comment into answer

Comment: Just posted it as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git never does operations like diff across a link. You must fetch the latest content from the server and then compare it:

```
git fetch origin master
git diff --cached FETCH_HEAD
```